# Media queries and Safari

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Here's my `index.html` :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Website</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-resolution: 96dpi)" type="text/css" href="css/app_normal.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-resolution: 97dpi) and (max-resolution: 192dpi)" type="text/css" href="css/app_medium.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-resolution: 193dpi)" type="text/css" href="css/app_hi.css"/>
```

This works fine on `Chrome` and `Firefox` (I don't care IE !) but not in `Safari`. How should I correct this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Safari still has partial support on this feature:
[**Link**](http://caniuse.com/#search=max-resolution)

From caniuse.com:

> While the standard uses min/max-resolution for this, some browsers support the older non-standard device-pixel-ratio media query.

Answer (score -1):

See the below link media Query Supported Browsers

[Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resolution#Browser_compatibility)